# How to show MediaPlayer position in MediaStyle notification - Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I am showing a MediaStyle notification for my app that includes a seek bar by setting the following playback state for the MediaSession:

```
mediaSession.setPlaybackState(
    PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
        .setActions(
            PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
                    or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE
                    or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_REWIND
                    or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD
                    or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO
        )
        .build()
)
```

Doing this enables the seek bar, and I have a function that handles the seek action, so that when I drag the seek bar and let go of it, it goes to that location in the audio, but the little circle on the seek bar is always at 0.

How can I get it to follow the currentPosition of the audio that's playing in real time?

Comment: Sending notification with sam id and currentmillies in intent can solve the issue

Comment: @PankajKumar can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I believe, that `MediaStyleNotifications`don't support progress.